# Vertica grant user create table

Tags: vertica

I have users (developers) in Vertica who need to create tables for testing purposes, which will later be deployed under specific production schema.
I do not want them to have the ability to create tables in the production schema though.

Im looking for the grants necessary to allow a user the ability to create tables. 
Do most environments create a schema for each user and then grant authorization for the user on that schema or what is the best practice?

Comment: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

1. Implement roles in you DB.
2. Manage grants on the schemas using roles definition.(single point)
3. Grant these roles to your users.

in regards users development, create a schema for each one of them with full rights (ownership) where they can play as much as they want.